# Генерирование контролов из XML

Tags: c#, xml, xmlparser

Добрый день.
Есть XML

```
<NewDataSet>
<OrganizationProperties>
    <OrganizationID>2118</OrganizationID>
    <FieldName>XMLTemplate</FieldName>

<FieldValue>
<billers  Col1Name="Key" Col2Name="Value">
    <MethodsList>
        <Method Name="строка вызова" type="Concatenate" ReadOnly="true" FieldName="@GMProp" Delimiter=""/>
    </MethodsList>
    <FieldsList>
        <Field label="ServiceId" Visible="false" Value="4"/>
        <Field label="@Prop" Visible="false" Value="msisdn=38" MethodName="строка вызова"/>
        <Field label="Телефон" Type="Целое число" IsObligatory="true" Value="050" MethodName="строка вызова" Stored="F1" Long="10"/>
        <Field label="ФИО" Type="ФИО" Stored="F2"/>
        <Field label="@GMProp" ReadOnly="true" Visible="false"/>
        <Field label="Сумма пополнения" Type="Дробное число" IsObligatory="true" Summable="true" Long="10,2"/>
        <Field label="@доп" ReadOnly="true" Visible="false" Value="; " MethodName="строка вызова"/>
    </FieldsList>
</billers>
</FieldValue>
<FieldOwner>true</FieldOwner>
    </OrganizationProperties>
  </NewDataSet>
```

В `<FieldsList>` находятся список полей, которые должны отобразиться на форме, а именно

`<Field label="Телефон" Type="Целое число" IsObligatory="true" Value="050" MethodName="строка вызова" Stored="F1" Long="10"/>`

Должен бить TextBox с именем `"Телефон"`, Text должен быть `"050"` и не превышать 10 симфолов.

и

`<Field label="Сумма пополнения" Type="Дробное число" IsObligatory="true" Summable="true" Long="10,2"/>`

Тоже `TextBox` с именем `"Сумма пополнения"`

Вопрос :

Есть ли какие-то паресеры, или как можно правильно сделать реализацию такого задания?

Спасибо.

Comment: Попробуйте [`XDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) в качестве парсера.

Answer (score 3):

Мне кажется, Вам следовало бы обратить внимание на [XAML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/apps/hh700354.aspx)

Comment: не получится. 
XML с контролами приходит в готовом виде.

Comment: Ну тут 2 варианта:

1 - сделать так, чтобы XML приходил в виде XAML,
2 - если нет возможности переделать источник XML, тогда вам придется парсить XML, и генерировать XAML на лету.

Но Я бы не обломался на вашем месте написать генератор форм WinForms. Судя по представленному куску XML, формы не очень сложные. Однажды Я уже что-то подобное делал)